# CSS Fluid width layout same height columns

Tags: html, css, layout

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18795563/index.html
How do i make the sidebar on the right the same height as the main content area on the left of it?
Without using JavaScript/JQuery or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Chris Coyier’s [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).